# How to add javax package in my android application

Tags: android, sprite

I want to add javax.microedition.lcdui.game package to my android application. When I create it manually eclipse shows the error

`The import javax.microedition.lcdui cannot be resolved`

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Preferences -> Android

There you can add additional jars and libs